# ChromeDriver shuts down as soon as chrome page opens

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I open a website with Selenium yet it shuts down as soon as I open it.

I tried creating an exit method and adding a teardown variable which I set to False. If the teardown = True, then the program should exit. It didn't work.

```
import types
import typing
import booking.constants as const
import os
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"/SeleniumDrivers/chromedriver_mac_arm64", teardown=False):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        self.teardown = teardown
        #self.options = Options()
        #self.options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(Booking, self).__init__()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if self.teardown:
            self.quit()

    def land_first_page(self):
        self.get(const.BASE_URL)
        #while(True):
        #    pass
```

The land_first_page() method opens the webpage; however, the below works when I uncomment the last two lines in the land_first_page() method:

```
import types
import typing
import booking.constants as const
import os
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"/SeleniumDrivers/chromedriver_mac_arm64", teardown=False):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        self.teardown = teardown
        #self.options = Options()
        #self.options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(Booking, self).__init__()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if self.teardown:
            self.quit()

    def land_first_page(self):
        self.get(const.BASE_URL)
        while(True):
           pass
```

How can I fix the above without using a while(True) statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the Python garbage collection,which causes the webdriver to close.

Lets try to add a method in your `Booking` class that keeps the driver open until you manually close it.

```
class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"/SeleniumDrivers/chromedriver_mac_arm64", teardown=False):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        self.teardown = teardown
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(Booking, self).__init__()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if self.teardown:
            self.quit()

    def land_first_page(self):
        self.get(const.BASE_URL)

    def keep_open(self):
        input("Press any key to quit...")
```

Then we can use it like that

```
bot = Booking(teardown=True)
bot.land_first_page()
bot.keep_open()
```